# Mostrar resultado con Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Trabajo con AngularJS v1, el problema es que no me muestra el resultado en la pagina solo me muestra `{{resultado}}` no me muestra el valor que contiene esa variable, muestro el código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="operacion">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Angular y bootstrap</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javasript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container text-center" ng-controller="preguntasController">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Angular JS + Bootstrap</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>¿Cuál es el resultado de la siguiente operación 6*9-12?</p>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".ventanaModal" ng-click="respuesta()" type="button">Calcular</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade ventanaModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h1>{{resultado}}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var miApp = angular.module('operacion', []);
    miApp.controller('preguntasController', function($scope){
        $scope.respuesta = function () {
            $scope.resultado = 6*9-12;
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Error:
[image: Error angular]

ruta del archivo `angular.min.js`
[image: ruta del archivo js]

[image: vs code]

Comment: revisa tu consola si tienes algún error? aparentemente es por un error de referencia en tus archivos javascript, creo que es el angular.min.js no lo estas referenciando bien.

Comment: @TheVicious Es verdad me da error dice que esta mal la referencia pero yo lo veo bien en la ruta correcta, llevo haciendo mas de 20 ejemplos y este no me funciona.

Comment: puedes mostrar el error de la consola, así sabemos en que estas fallando.

Comment: @TheVicious Actualizado el post

Comment: En tu ruta local cuando haces la peticion angular.min.js <script type="text/javasript" src="angular.min.js"></script> Fijate que este correcto el directorio donde esta el archivo js

Comment: **<script type="text/javasript" src="angular.min.js"></script>** esta ruta esta mal referenciada tienes que poner **js/angular.min.js**

Comment: @TheVicious Esta así, ya actualice el post es que lo movi a una carpeta e igual sigue fallando.

Answer (score 0):

Usando CDNs funciona, debe ser algún error en las rutas

```js
var miApp = angular.module('operacion', []);
miApp.controller('preguntasController', function($scope) {
  $scope.respuesta = function() {
    $scope.resultado = 6 * 9 - 12;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="operacion">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Angular y bootstrap</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-eSi1q2PG6J7g7ib17yAaWMcrr5GrtohYChqibrV7PBE=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-VsEqElsCHSGmnmHXGQzvoWjWwoznFSZc6hs7ARLRacQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div class="container text-center" ng-controller="preguntasController">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Angular JS + Bootstrap</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>¿Cuál es el resultado de la siguiente operación 6*9-12?</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".ventanaModal" ng-click="respuesta()" type="button">Calcular</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade ventanaModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h1>{{resultado}}</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Lo rato es que antes funcionaba y ahora no, he cambiado de ruta el archivo js de angular, lo he vuelto a descargar y me sigue dando el mismo problema, efectivamente si funciona con CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Ya vi el error gracias a todos por su tiempo.
Error

```
<script type="text/javasript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Correción

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Faltaba una "c"

Saludos!